# Setting the value of HTML5 input type=week thru jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, momentjs

How to set the default value of HTML5's **input type="week"** in Javascript/Jquery? I'm using moment.js to make things easier.

**HTML**

```
<input type="week" id="weekpicker" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#weekpicker').val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it (using momentjs): http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

```
$('#weekpicker').val(moment().weekYear() + "-W" + moment().week());
```

First I get the **weekYear** (not the year, *Because the first day of the first week does not always fall on the first day of the year, sometimes the week-year will differ from the month year.* source: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week-year/) then I concatenated a letter **"W"** as the format requires, then I get the **week**. I added it all together and got:  **2014-W47**

Answer (score 1):

Using the default format it will be like this: 'yyyy-**W**ww'

```
<input type="week" value="2014-W02">
```

Above gives the 2nd week of 2014.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/oLs6Lseh/1/

Comment: This does not include the javascript code to set the value but this helped me get the proper format of the value. Thanks