# How to set the value to today of a week input

Tags: html, input, default-value

Basically if I typed

```
<input type="week">
```

What do I type to set the default value to today's week?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the value of HTML5 input type=week thru jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966574/setting-the-value-of-html5-input-type-week-thru-jquery)

Comment: If I can get +way too much for nice exec this can get an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by the following.

`<input type="week" value="<?php echo date('Y').'-W'.date('W');?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Link http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.week.html will have all the details regarding input type="week".

```
 <input type="week" name="year_week" value="2017-W42">
```

Comment: Please add an explanation too for the answer posted

Comment: As 2017 define the year and with a prefix of -w will define the week number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
<input type="week" name="year_weeks" value="2017-W20">
```

For More info please click here [HTML5 input type=week](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.week.html#input.week)

[See example here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_week_get)

It will work on latest chrome & IE browser.